# Can I manually write an entery into journald using Python?

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to manually write an entry into journald from Python. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any insights.

-Paul

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588421/how-to-log-to-journald-systemd-via-python

Answer (score 2):

If by `journald` you are referring to the `systemd journal`, then a simple search for "journald python api" yields:

https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd

### Usage

Quick example:

```
from systemd import journal

journal.send('Hello world')
journal.send('Hello, again, world', FIELD2='Greetings!', FIELD3='Guten tag')
journal.send('Binary message', BINARY=b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef')
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to both Python and Linux. Thank you for pointing me to this; I'll check it out.