# How to log to journald (systemd) via Python?

Tags: python, logging, systemd, python-logging

I would like `logging.info()` to go to journald (systemd).

Up to now I only found python modules which read journald (not what I want) or modules which work like this: `journal.send('Hello world')`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[python-systemd](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/) has a [JournalHandler](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/master/systemd/journal.py) you can use with the logging framework.

From the documentation:

```
import logging
from systemd.journal import JournalHandler

log = logging.getLogger('demo')
log.addHandler(JournalHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info("sent to journal")
```

Comment: Could you help take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748156/python3-journal-logging-does-not-show-log-level?

Comment: from systemd.journal import JournalHandler
has error, instead : 
from systemd import journal
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(journal.JournaldLogHandler())

Comment: Is there no way to set the **unit**? This is a very serious limitation.

Comment: @Federico I can't find a way to set the unit, but you can do `JournalHandler(SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=<id>)`, and then `<id>` is used for the unit/id field in the corresponding log entries (if you don't set this, then the file name is used by default; [see the source](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/blob/a402d08da41413507a4ebebf18de897f7ddf1dd2/systemd/journal.py#L562-L563)). However, this doesn't create a `<id>` unit, so `journalctl -u <id>` doesn't produce any output. But you can filter the `<id>` msgs with `journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=<id>`.

Comment: Note that confusingly, the package name on pypi is actually [systemd-python](https://pypi.org/project/systemd-python/) not python-systemd

Comment: JournalHandler has been renamed to JournaldLogHandler, like in the other answer

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to the official package, the [systemd package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/systemd) works with python 3.6. Its source is also on [github](https://github.com/mosquito/python-systemd).

The implementation is a mirror of the official lib, with some minor changes:

```
import logging
from systemd import journal

log = logging.getLogger('demo')
log.addHandler(journal.JournaldLogHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info("sent to journal")
```

or for an even shorter method:

```
from systemd import journal

journal.write("Hello Lennart")
```

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure what's up with your system, but this definitely works. I created a simple example Vagrantfile which will start a system with python 3.5, install the systemd package, and execute the example: https://gist.github.com/schlueter/ce1f2e32ef350bfa21e1b8b8605711b6.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding additional logging options, other than `log.info(message)`. Are there equivalent methods, like `log.warning(message)`?

Comment: @charliesneath The logger class is unrelated to the systemd package except that it is the interface by which the systemd package is used. See its documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html.

Comment: The official package is widely available and recommended.

Comment: @Federico I stated no opinion on whether to use this, it's just an option which I encountered.

Comment: @bschlueter to clarify: it's recommended by systemd.

Comment: @Federico Cool. Not everyone can just use the libraries recommended by the organizations which maintain the tools they use. Sometimes they can't because those libraries are missing a feature they need. This is one of the advantages of open source software that you can always make your own version of something or something new entirely. Or you can use library recommended by some entity. Your choice.

Comment: On my system `journal.write()` does not exist but `journal.send("Hello Lennart")` works!

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution without third party modules.
It works fine for me and the messages show up in journald.

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# this is just to make the output look nice
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(name)s.%(levelname)s: %(message)s", datefmt="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

# this logs to stdout and I think it is flushed immediately
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('test')
```

Comment: Messages also show up in journald with the default `sys.stderr` stream for me.

Comment: I like vanilla solutions :))

Comment: cannot confirm that, neither by using stderr not stdout

Comment: this code does nothing related to journald. You are probably forgetting to mention that you run a script as a systemd service, and in that case systemd will collect stdout and stderr from a program and pass it to journald anyway, so you can even use `print` and it will still end up in journald.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It depends on the context the code is running in.

Answer (score -1):

This is an alternative solution without third party modules

````
import subprocess

data = "sent to journal"
echoCmd = ["echo", data]
sysdCat = ["systemd-cat", "-p", "info"]

echoResult = subprocess.Popen(echoCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
sysdCatResult = subprocess.Popen(sysdCat, stdin=echoResult.stdout)
sysdCatResult.communicate()
```
````