# How to see the systemd service logs in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, systemd

I have a below service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=demo service
Requisite=mosquitto.service
BindsTo=mosquitto.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/john/Documents/source/demo.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This `demo.service` simply calls a python code `demo.py`. When I am starting the service using `sudo systemctl start demo.service`, it always remains in `auto-restart(failure)` mode.

```
demo.service - demo service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-17 12:13:37 BST; 23s ago
  Process: 4744 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/john/Documents/source/demo.py
 Main PID: 4744 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I have checked `syslog` but there is no useful information in them. It just shows demo service started and demo service stopped logs.

From where can I get its logs to understand why the service is not starting. Please help. Thanks

Below are the logs from `journactl`:

```
Aug 13 13:51:40 john systemd[1]: Started demo service.
Aug 13 13:51:40 john systemd[1]: demo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 13 13:51:40 john systemd[1]: demo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 13 13:52:10 john systemd[1]: demo.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 13 13:52:10 john systemd[1]: demo.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Aug 13 13:52:10 john systemd[1]: Stopped demo service.
```

Comment: Can you post the code of demo.py?

Comment: For some reason I cannot post the code but is there anything I need to include in the code which will show some logs in journactl

Comment: you can try [systemd package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604392/13782669) to logging

Answer (score 14):

To view the logged `stdout` and `stderr` you can use [journalctl](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/journalctl.1.en.html)  command:

```
sudo journalctl -u [service_name]
```

Comment: I have updated the question with journactl logs. It doesn't seems to help. How can I check what caused service to go into inactive state.

Comment: Yes, you can get full list by `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service`

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo journalctl -u [service_name] -e
```

the -e option at end jumps to end of the logfile to see most recent logs.